# If I offer a bounty on someone else's question, do I receive the positive votes in that question?

Tags: support, bounty

I have that doubt. But, seems not have response. If not, why to offer a bounty  to others?

*Note: This question is because I have this doubt a time ago, I'm not looking for ways for get upvotes or increase my reputation*

Thanks.

Comment: Because you want the answer? You bounty to get an answer to a question... Not upvotes... Actually you put a bounty to attract attention to a question, hoping someone will answer it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your reputation is unaffected by the votes on someone else's question, even if you put a bounty on it.

> If not, why to offer a bounty to others?

Maybe because you derive some *other benefit* from the bounty. For instance, you have the same issue but none of the answers satisfy you (or it has no answer yet). So you do it to get a solution that works for you, which is to your benefit.

Or maybe you want to bring attention to an existing answer that you think is excellent and should get more attention (and likely upvotes). Sometimes superior answers are posted much later and suffer in comparison to earlier answers that managed to accrue votes over the years. Bringing attention to such answers benefits the common good, which is something that perhaps you care about.

Comment: thanks! that's I was looking for. I read [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) but my question was not in the list

Answer (score 0):

You receive **no** reputation for placing a bounty on another person's question.

Instead, you ***lose*** the amount of the bounty placed on their question (between 50 and 500 reputation), which is not refunded except under exigent circumstances.

One uses bounties to bring attention to questions, or to further award an existing answer on a question.  Effectively, one is frequently *giving* reputation in the hopes of a more detailed and better answer on a specific question.

Meta Stack Exchange [has a detailed FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) in regards to how bounties work.

Comment: I had read how works bounties but I had no idea why people offered it. Thanks for clarification